# How to deal with IP redirection and Googlebot?

Tags: seo, redirects, googlebot, internationalization, geotargeting

My client wants country-based domains for their customers. For example, all customers from UK will be taken to the `.co.uk` site, even if they visit the `.com` site. And same for other countries.

I have used IP redirection for this. Redirection is OK.

Since all non-UK IPs are redirected to `.com` site, how will Google index the `.co.uk` site?

If I submit a sitemap of `.co.uk` and `.com` sites to Google and have country-based IP redirection in place, will Google (or any other bot) be able to visit?

My understanding is, Google bots have IPs from USA.

And, `.co.uk` and `.com` sites have 80 % content same. Will it impact on duplicate content?

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't like automatic redirects based on geo-ip, because on this way the Googlebot and human visitors are forced to visit certain site/folder. Beside of this, wrong handling of similar content on different tld-domains will cause duplicate content issues.

The strategy Google recommends looks like:

- main domain with hreflangs,
- on first visit of human visitor - set cookie with country/language information, on further visits - redirect visitor according to cookie settings,
- googlebot doesn't work with cookies - it entries everywhere it wants and reads sites only according to hreflangs.

Comment: Client wants to force each visitor to country based domain strictly. I guess they got something to hide.